# Does Google restrict distributing Android apps to BETA customers outside of the marketplace

Tags: android

We are developing iOS and Adroid apps for a service we are building.  Apple has specific rules and limitations associated with distributing apps outside of the App store for use in BETA testing.  I know how to distribute the apk file to our BETA customers outside of the Google marketplace, however are there any legal limitations or requirements for registering BETA customers when using this approach?

Answer (score 3):

No You can distribute a BETA. They will just have to enable a option to allow outside sources to install a application. When the user tried to install it it will give them this option to enable it.

Comment: You may want to include a License agreement if it is user's whom you do not know.